# Push full project not just changes using ftploy

Tags: git, ftp, bitbucket

I am trying to use the [ftploy](http://ftploy.com) service to deploy a git repo from [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) to my ftp hosting account. It works fine but it only deploys files that have been changed. Is there any way that I can get it to deploy the complete project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it to work by deleting the project in ftploy, creating it again and this time ticking the "deploy" button.

Comment: once you have created a project without clicking deploy you cant go back and select it but you can go to https://ftploy.com/dashboard/projects/deploynow/project_id which is where you get directed if you were to have selected deploy in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the tip. for me it didnt even start deploying changed files until i removed and re-created the project with the deploy button ticked. confusing stuff.

Comment: Hi @prms and welcome to stack overflow ... just to let you know you're not supposed to use answers as comments - stack exchange sites have fairly strict rules ( to keep it a reliable source of information ) ... just in case someone votes you down and you wonder why.

Comment: Thanks @byronyasgur, i wasn't aware of this... However, I did want to provide some additional information to your initial answer: cause for me NOTHING got deployed until I re-created the project – not even changed files.

Comment: Yes it's great to do that ... stack exchange is a great setup, much better than a typical forum but you need to take time to figure out "how to do things" to make it work ... have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help and here http://stackoverflow.com/about ... you get a badge for reading all that one ;-)

Comment: @byronyasgur i just realised why i've made that mistake: you cannot comment on an answer (what i've tried initially) until you have 50 points rep – which i haven't, obviously. And to keep this on-topic: after a lot of trouble with ftploy i've decided to swtich to [dploy.io](http://dploy.io) – really nice and no trouble so far!

Comment: Might try that one. Didn't know about the > 50 pts for comment rule ... strange.